# glossaries child numbering

Tags: enumerate, glossaries

I'm using `enumerate` in my glossaries entries. Some entries have children. The default for children is numbering with the same style as `enumerate`. Is there any way to change the child numbering from Arabic to Roman numerals?

Here's a basic document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[toc, acronym, index, nopostdot, xindy, %symbols,
        numberedsection=autolabel, subentrycounter=true]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\setglossarystyle{tree}


\newglossaryentry{parent}{
    name={parent},
    description={
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item
                stuff
            \item
                stuff
            \item
                stuff
        \end{enumerate}
    }
}

\newglossaryentry{child}{
    name={child, I should have a Roman numeral},
    description={
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item
                child stuff
            \item
                child stuff
            \item
                child stuff
        \end{enumerate}
    },
    parent={parent}
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

You'll need to use this `xindy` command to get everything up:

```
xindy -L english -C utf8 -I xindy -M glossaries_child_number -t glossaries_child_number.glg -o glossaries_child_number.gls glossaries_child_number.glo
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document, not just a feature request

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The counter which is responsible of child entries is `glossarysubentry`. So simply add the line

```
\renewcommand*{\glssubentrycounterlabel}{\Roman{glossarysubentry})\space}
```

in your preamble (you already have `subentrycounter=true` when calling `glossaries`)

MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[toc, acronym, index, nopostdot, xindy, %symbols,
        numberedsection=autolabel, subentrycounter=true]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\setglossarystyle{tree}
\renewcommand*{\glssubentrycounterlabel}{\Roman{glossarysubentry})\space}

\newglossaryentry{parent}{
    name={parent},
    description={
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item
                stuff
            \item
                stuff
            \item
                stuff
        \end{enumerate}
    }
}

\newglossaryentry{child}{
    name={child},
    description={
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item
                I should have a Roman numeral numbering me.
            \item
                child stuff
            \item
                child stuff
        \end{enumerate}
    },
    parent={parent}
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: My labelling was confusing. I'm looking for something like`I) child` with `1) child stuff`. I've changed the question accordingly.

Comment: @blalterman Sorry for misunderstanding. Changed the answer accordingly...